# Forbidden when RestTemplate call an external API (Cloudflare server)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm using one REST API inside my REST service. Everything works when I call the API from Chrome or Postman, but a Forbbiden response is returned when I call from my application.

PS: I'm using a Java Spring Boot project.

**Test Method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String uri = "https://swapi.co/api/planets?search=Alderaan";
    System.out.println(new RestTemplate().getForObject(uri, String.class));
}
```

**Produces:**

```
20:58:01.436 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET swapi.co/api/planets?search=Alderaan 
20:58:01.461 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
20:58:02.577 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 403 FORBIDDEN
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

The external API: https://swapi.co/documentation

Comment: Did you also use Spring Security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works when I specify some "user-agent" in the Headers.

It seams to be a restriction on CloudFlare:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-

The user-agent of my application is my Java version (Java/1.8.0_151). If you try this user-agent you will receive a restrict access message from CloudFlare.

**curl:**

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_151" https://swapi.co/api/planets/?search=Alderaan
```

**response:** Access denied | swapi.co used Cloudflare to restrict access

**This code solve the problem:**

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.add("user-agent", "Application");
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

 String planetFound = restTemplate.exchange(findPlanetUri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
```

**Another solution:**

```
 String planetFound = restTemplate.getForObject(findPlanetUri, String.class);
```

and

```
   @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        ClientHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = (request, body, execution) -> {
            request.getHeaders().add("user-agent", "Application");
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        };
        return restTemplateBuilder.additionalInterceptors(interceptor).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works for me:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String uri = "https://swapi.co/api/planets?search=Alderaan";
    System.out.println(new RestTemplate().getForObject(uri, String.class));
}
```

The output is:

```
01:20:49.564 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET https://swapi.co/api/planets?search=Alderaan
01:20:49.573 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
01:20:51.177 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
01:20:51.179 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json"
{"count":1,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"name":"Alderaan","rotation_period":"24","orbital_period":"364","diameter":"12500","climate":"temperate","gravity":"1 standard","terrain":"grasslands, mountains","surface_water":"40","population":"2000000000","residents":["https://swapi.co/api/people/5/","https://swapi.co/api/people/68/","https://swapi.co/api/people/81/"],"films":["https://swapi.co/api/films/6/","https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"],"created":"2014-12-10T11:35:48.479000Z","edited":"2014-12-20T20:58:18.420000Z","url":"https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"}]}
```

Maybe you have sent too many requests to a service within a minute or an hour and they have started to block your IP / User Agent or what so ever.

Comment: The same code that you used:
20:58:01.436 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET https://swapi.co/api/planets?search=Alderaan
20:58:01.461 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
20:58:02.577 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 403 FORBIDDEN

Comment: I'll edit my question with your code to make more simple. Tks

Comment: @VictorSoares have you tried to contact support (or developer) behind the "swapi.co" service about that? Maybe they have some kind of DDOS protection system and you are affected. Also, do you use any kind of proxy to access "swapi.co" service?

Comment: Ah! I see your own answer to your question: as I suspected, you were blocked by DDOS protection system that has simple rules to filter out request sent by certain user-agents.

Comment: exactly Vladimir